# Ubuntu launch blender instances with a different configuration

Tags: linux

I am moving from Mac to Linux (Ubuntu) to use Blender (it gives me the feeling that it is more stable and, above all, faster).
The problem I have is the following: On Mac I had a script, to run an instance of each version of Blender, in which I defined the variable ENV: `$BLENDER_USER_CONFIG` and `$BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS`, so that the program started with a different configuration ( startup file and installed addons) depending on the version (if you launched the script for 2.83 it came with certain addons or if you launched the 2.79 or 2.90a with others).
In Ubuntu I have managed to configure a .desktop for each version so that it launches the corresponding instance but... does anyone know how to define the ENV variables for each .desktop so that they have their different path to config and scripts?
I hope I explained myself well...
Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: You can change the Exec line in the .desktop file like this:

```
Exec=env YOUR_VAR1=value1 YOUR_VAR2=value2 /opt/blender-2.90/blender %f
```

*(Duplicated my answer from blender.community :) )*

Comment: Hi michaelh!
Did not work at all...
This is my Exec line: Exec=env BLENDER_USER_CONFIG=/Home/daniel/Dropbox/apps/BLENDER/CONF/2.83/config BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS=/Home/daniel/Dropbox/apps/BLENDER/CONF/2.83/scripts /opt/blender2.83/blender %f