# Is there an easier way to customize Blender 3D "New" file selections

Tags: customization

I use Blender 3D for both 3D Printing and 3D Animations. I created a startup.blend file for 3D printing, that is perfect for my printer bed, and added a bunch of 3D printing related add-ons, removed the camera and lights.

For my work, I also do a bit of 3D animations for clients. When doing the animations, I always start with my custom startup.blend file, but then I have to go in a add lights, camera, etc to setup for my animations.

I have modified the blender "New" file menu (and the New file startup screen) by modifying Blender.app (MacOS). I did this by duplicating the VFX folder located at:

`/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.3/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/VFX`

... I called it **3D_Printing**, and editing the files. Now I have this option in both places.

[image]

[image]

My solution is going to be wiped out when I update Blender and will have to do this all over again.

**My question is, is there an easier way, or an official way of doing this?**

Edit/Answer:

Based on the comments, it looks like you create a Template! For macOS, I did this:

1. Created "startup" folder in the /Users/dougjones/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.3/scripts directory.
2. Inside "startup" created these directories: /startup/bl_app_templates_user/
3. I moved my "3D_Printing" directory in there, and everything is working as it should!

Comment: See if using [Templates](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html) helps for your use

Comment: Maybe related (question was about Windows, but you can adopt it for Mac): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284757/

Comment: Seems like Templates are the way to go! Thanks John and quellenform!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it looks like you create a Blender Template! For macOS, I did this:

1. Created "startup" folder in the /Users/dougjones/Library/Application
   Support/Blender/3.3/scripts directory.
2. Inside "startup" created these directories: /startup/bl_app_templates_user/
3. I moved my "3D_Printing" directory into the "bl_app_templates_user", and everything is working as it should!