# How to add multiple startup files, with different names?

Tags: python, customization, startup-file

How is it possible (with or without coding) to create more startup options without replacing the old ones?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284757/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using templates:

[image]

To create a new one, dig into blender install directory and add the blend file you want (named as "startup.blend") in it.

[image]

If there is an integrated way to do it (from a Blender function or UI access), I don't know it.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm using Linux now but I was able to find the folder in pretty much the same spot:
/snap/blender/current/3.4/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/